# Multiline UILabel inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uilabel

I can't make multiple lines for a label inside the scroll view. Though it perfectly works outside of a scrollview. See picture below for details. The scroll view has a horizontal scroll.

[image]

**UPD**: ScrollView and label constraints:

[image]

Comment: @rocky Well, there's nothing to show. This is basically it!

Answer (score 2):

So apparently I need explicitly set `ScrollView` `contentSize`. Also to get this size I need to  know it from a label which is a bit tricky here. The full code goes below:

```
// create a label as usual
let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = "really long label text..."

// place it with a nice offset and set its width explicitly using parent view width
// after which `sizeToFit` does a trick and adjusts it's height
label.frame.offset(dx: 16.0, dy: 16.0)
label.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width - 32
label.sizeToFit()

// now add it to the scroll view and set content size to label size plus margin at the bottom
self.scrollView.addSubview(label)
self.scrollView.contentSize = label.frame.size
self.scrollView.contentSize.height += 32
```